# How to pass props to multiple dumb components - redux / reactJs?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using the below code to pass the data to react component. I am trying to figure out a way to pass the data to more than one dumb react component but not sure how to achieve that. Can someone let me know how to pass props to multiple react (dumb) components?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Results from '../components/displayResults';


@connect(
  state => ({results: state.results})
)
export default class  extends Component {
  render () {
    return <Results  { ...this.props }/>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The below solution seems to work fine.

```
....
import Results from '../components/displayResults';
import Sample from '../components/sample';

    @connect(
      state => ({results: state.results})
    )
    export default class extends Component {
      render () {
        return(
        <div>
        <Results  { ...this.props }/>
        <Sample  { ...this.props }/>
        </div>
      )
      }
    }
```